# Нестандартные HTML теги

Tags: html

Можно ли самому создавать свои нестандартные HTML-теги? Например `<page></page>`

Comment: На этот вопрос и так можно дать однозначный ответ.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**По спецификации**: да, можно, но их имя должно содержать хотя бы один дефис.

**Реально**: да, можно - браузеры всё съедят. За исключением старых IE, где нужно вызывать document.createElement для всех незнакомых ему тегов, чтобы они не стали самозакрывающимися.

А ещё, можно создавать теги в своих пространствах имён.

[Спецификация](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-custom-elements-20141216/).

Comment: ммм понятно спасибо!

Comment: еще бы ссылочку на спецификацию :)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-custom-elements-20141216/

Answer (score 11):

Да, разумеется. http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/

Вот легковесный полифил `document.registerElement` для всех актуальных браузеров: https://github.com/WebReflection/document-register-element

Рекомендую его, т.к. сам активно использую в продакшене.

```
var MyElement = document.registerElement(
  'my-element',
  {
    prototype: Object.create(
      HTMLElement.prototype, {
      createdCallback: {value: function() {
        console.log('here I am ^_^ ');
        console.log('with content: ', this.textContent);
      }},
      attachedCallback: {value: function() {}},
      detachedCallback: {value: function() {}},
      attributeChangedCallback: { value: function(name, previousValue, value ) {}}
    })
  }
);
```

Кастомные теги повышают семантичность и рекомендуются к применению W3C и Google. Единственная проблема с ними - непрохождение стандартного валидатора.

Проблем со стилями на практике не наблюдал ни разу.

Обратите внимание, что по стандарту, кастомные теги должны содержать в названии черту `-`, т.е. в вашем случае `<my-page>`

Comment: Стоит добавить, что перед тем как придумывать свои теги, стоит внимательно ознакомиться с функцией каждого из стандартных, в т.ч. новых тегов html5: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_new_elements.asp

Answer (score 2):

Можно, но к нему не будут применяться стили в некоторых старых браузерах, [тут](http://www.stijit.com/html-css/html5shiv-js-ie-support) можно почитать как добавить поддержку, но я бы не советовал выдумывать такие велосипеды

Comment: надо срочно рассказать авторам Angular, Vue, React, knockout и пр