# Собственные теги в HTML

Tags: html

Можно ли создавать собственные теги в HTML? Насколько это допустимо? Будут ли они нормально отображаться в старых браузерах?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/450084/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-html-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8

Comment: Конечно можно.
Вот пример: http://vismech.ru/html/svoi-tegi-v-html/