# Содержит ли normal elements - custom elements?

Tags: html

Входит ли **[custom elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-elements)** в группу **[normal elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#elements-2)**?

Из одной главы я понял что существуют несколько типов групп элементов, самая большая это **normal elements**. Но я так и не понял входит ли туда **custom elements**.

В пункте сказано:

> **Normal elements:** All other allowed **[HTML elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#html-elements)** are normal elements

[В этой ссылке](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#html-elements) говорится что любые определения в пространстве содержатся в http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml

А также цитата:

> The term "HTML elements" refers to any element in that namespace, even in XML documents.

Но вот определения **custom elements** нет в http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml , значит ли это что **custom elements** не входит в группу **normal elements**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все исходит из того, что XHTML является подмножеством языка XML. В языке XML вы можете создавать и использовать абсолютно любые теги, которые только ваша душа пожелает. Это Custom Elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Планеты>
  <Планета ID="1">
    <Название>Меркурий</Название>
  </Планета >
  <Планета ID="2">
    <Название>Сатурн</Название>
  </Планета >
</Планеты>
```

А в XHTML прописаны только известные браузерам теги для которые он может генерировать внешний вид, эти элементы называются Normal Elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="ru" lang="ru">
  <head>
    <title>Заголовок</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    Содержимое документа
  </body>
</html>
```

То есть по факту Custom Elements это огромная группа элементов в которую так же (теоретически) входят и Normal Elements. Но шанс встретить Custom Elements в разметке мизерный.

Правда стандарт HTML накладывает ограничения на имена Custom Elements: [RuSO: Нестандартные HTML теги](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/450084/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-html-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8/450102#450102)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/450102/178988

Comment: Про подмножество ясно. Но вы так и не ответили на вопрос: *входит ли **custom elements** в группу **normal elements***?

Comment: @Qwertiy а это просто правила которые формируют корректный custom element. По факту тег можно любой написать только он сформируется некорректно. Прототип будет другой.

Comment: То есть глава 12 живет отдельно от главы 4.13? Хотя смотрите если внимательно присмотреться то в главе 4 в целом описываются HTML elements (более конкретно). А если так то custom elements это HTML элемент как и любой другой (<br>,<a>,<p> итд). От сюда выходит закономерный вопрос почему это custom elements не является HTML elements?

Comment: @MaximPro, просто зачем вам это? Есть язык высшего порядка XML и на его основе сделан HTML. В грубом приближении это и есть XML в котором описан список необходимых тегов, а так же спецификация, которая поясняет как этот список тегов должен обрабатываться браузером и показываться визуально пользователю. Но XML может включать кучу тегов и в данном случае это попытка их впихнуть в модель HTML - вы делаете их частью HTML на минимальном уровне. Эта часть написана для разработчиков браузеров и говорит как им поступать, если они встретили незнакомый тег или они хотят внедрить еще что-то: SVG, MathML.

Comment: Мне интересно поэтому и спрашиваю. `SVG`, `MathML` - **foreign elements**. В данном случае же спецификация HTML, а не XML. Опять же вы конкретно и не ответили на предыдущий комментарий.

Comment: @MaximPro спецификация в первую очередь написана для разработчиков браузеров, а не для тех, кто хочет упорядочить свои знания. Обратите внимание в каждом абзаце есть слова: **this section is non-normative**. В данном случае глава включена для того, чтобы знать как работать с элементом, который не прописан в HTML Elements и не является часть normal elements. Custom elements относятся к категории Custom которые являются Dom Elements и прописан вообще в DOM Standard. Поэтому мой ответ остается прежним: нет, не входят. Вы слишком формально подходите к документу, который на это не рассчитан.

Comment: Ага, вашу позицию понял...логично, исходя из того какую я логику изначально приложил. Я пока подожду мало ли еще кто захочет ответить. Если ответов не будет я приму ваш ответ как окончательный.

Comment: Еще хочу кое-что спросить. Я не нашел категории **Custom** в https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/ Она где-то в другом месте находится?

Comment: @MaximPro про Custom Elements [я взял отсюда](https://www.w3.org/TR/custom-elements/), в заметке ссылки ведут в DOM и другие документы связанные с Custom Elements (в том числе на упомянутую HTML Specification 4.13). В DOM это описание **4.9. Interface Element** и там дальше при наведении на custom еще куча ссылок на различные части документа. Обратите внимание на Abstract в ссылке, в нем указано, что это все-таки DOM elements в документе.

Comment: Ага, то есть конкретно категории под названием **custom** нет, я понял. А и еще такой вопрос: эти правила https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#start-tags применяются к **custom elements**?

Comment: @MaximPro да, применяются.

Comment: Чтобы уточнить терминологию, есть категория **custom** или нет? В моем понимании есть просто раздел под названием **custom elements**, который описывает поведение пользовательских элементов так? Или все таки есть категория **custom**? Спрашиваю, для того, чтобы каши в голове не было.

Comment: @MaximPro просто custom нет. Есть категория Custom Elements, это категория DOM Elements у которых внутреннее состояние custom element state установлено в значение custom. Я это понимаю как-то так из описания W3C.

Comment: Ага, все понятно